# CSS absolute positioning with respect to its parent div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to arrange two divs like the image below.

[image]

So, what I tried is this.

```
<div class="popup">
    <div class="close-button">
    <a class="close" href="#">
        <img alt="" src="/images/lb/close.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my css:

```
.close-button {position:absolute; top:-0.5em; right:-0.5em; z-index:10;}
```

However, my x button is positioned with respect to root `div`, and display x button in top right corner of the browser.

Is there a way to set absolute position to its parent instead of setting it to root element?

Thank you.

Comment: Set to his parent position: relative;

Comment: @LuisP.A.like this? `.popup{position:relative;}` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do absolute positioning based on the parent, the parent must be positioned using relative.

```
.popup {
    position: relative;
}

. close-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: -0.5em;
    right: -0.5em;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.popup {
 position:relative;
}
```